# JHipster: How to display customized error messages to users

Tags: jhipster

I am using JHipster v6.6.0 and I want to display customized error messages to users.

This question has been asked before and answered by using the class **CustomParameterizedException**.

But I can not find this class in the JHipster version that I am using.

Has the class been removed? And if so, what can be used instead?

Comment: Have you considered adding your custom exception to ExceptionTranslator class?

Answer (score 3):

The class `CustomParameterizedException` was removed in [PR#9624](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/9624) in favor of the [Problem](https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web) library.

Quoting the documentation on [Managing Server Errors](https://www.jhipster.tech/managing-server-errors/):

> To handle Spring MVC REST errors, JHipster uses [Zalando’s Problem Spring Web library](https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web), in order to provide rich, JSON-based error messages.

You can achieve the same custom error messages as before with less effort and more customization options.

```java
import org.zalando.problem.Problem;
import org.zalando.problem.Status;
...
throw Problem.builder()
             .withStatus(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
             .with("param1", "value 1")
             .with("param2", "value 2")
             .build();
```

If you notice, this is how JHipster handles errors in base components (users, accounts, authorization).

Check the `ExceptionTranslator.java` class for examples and guidance. A good place to start would be `handleMethodArgumentNotValid()` I think, but my experience with the Problem library is very limited.